# How to use Cython to create a stand dll

Tags: python, dll

I have a Python script, I renamed the script to .pyx file. I want compile this code to a stand dll file.

I saw in [this document](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/tutorial.html) that Cython will create a dll file, but i only get a pyd.

I have mingw and try to use command `python setup.py build --compiler=mingw32` to compile the script my code (just a hello world):

```
def init():
    return "hello world"
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: This is not what Cython is for. It's for writing CPython extension in a Python dialect that can and should be used to write low-level statically-typed code that has to work closely with Python. Not for converting python code into something that can be called into from unrelated code (e.g. C programs that don't know about CPython).

Answer (score 9):

So the first thing to do is rename the
file to helloworld.pyx. Now we need to
make the setup.py, which is like a
python Makefile (for more information
see Compilation). Your setup.py should
look like:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension

from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
    setup(
        cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
        ext_modules = [Extension("helloworld",
    ["helloworld.pyx"])] )
```

To use this to build your Cython file
use the commandline options:

```
$ python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

Which will leave a file in your local
directory called helloworld.so in unix
or helloworld.dll in Windows.

Now to
use this file: start the python
interpreter and simply import it as if
it was a regular python module:

Comment: thanks. i do it the same as you ,in xp sp3.but i can not get a helloworld.dll,but there is a helloword.pyd,and a build folder.this is i want know why no dll fill

Comment: @JaKob Bowyer  I am getting .c extension file if I am run the same command given above. May I know why I am getting .c extension instead of .dll file.

Answer (score 6):

> [**Is a *.pyd file the same as a
>   DLL?**](http://docs.python.org/faq/windows.html#is-a-pyd-file-the-same-as-a-dll)
>
> Yes, .pyd files are dll’s, but there are a few differences. If you
>   have a DLL named `foo.pyd`, then it must have a function `PyInit_foo()`.
>   You can then write Python “import foo”, and Python will search for
>   foo.pyd (as well as foo.py, foo.pyc) and if it finds it, will attempt
>   to call `PyInit_foo()` to initialize it. You do not link your .exe with
>   foo.lib, as that would cause Windows to require the DLL to be present.
>
> Note that the search path for foo.pyd is PYTHONPATH, not the same as
>   the path that Windows uses to search for foo.dll. Also, foo.pyd need
>   not be present to run your program, whereas if you linked your program
>   with a dll, the dll is required. Of course, foo.pyd is required if you
>   want to say `import foo`. In a DLL, linkage is declared in the source
>   code with `__declspec(dllexport)`. In a .pyd, linkage is defined in a
>   list of available functions.

[Modifying Python’s Search Path](https://docs.python.org/2/install/index.html#modifying-python-s-search-path), [Absolute and Relative Imports](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-328-absolute-and-relative-imports)