# Stand-alone dynamic library from Python

Tags: python, dll, dllimport, cython, py2exe

Is it possible to compile Cython code to a dynamic library (e.g. dll) using something like --embed flag?

e.g. renaming pyd file to dll only shows the init method using dependency walker

related questions:

[How to use Cython to create a stand dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170406/how-to-use-cython-to-create-a-stand-dll)
[Can Cython compile to an EXE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581784/can-cython-compile-to-an-exe)

Comment: Protip: if the answer to your question (in this format, yes/no) is too short to even post as an answer without adding a length filler, it's not a good question. This sort of question would be better asked in the Python Chat Room.

Comment: @RUJordan as you can see I expanded the question and described the problem with references

Answer (score 0):

It looks like creating a COM DLL from py2exe is better approach:

http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Py2exeAndCtypesComDllServer

```
  23     my_com_server_target = Target(
  24     description = "my com server",
  25     # use module name for ctypes.com dll server
  26     modules = ["dir.my_com_server"],
  27     # the following line embeds the typelib within the dll
  28     other_resources = [("TYPELIB", 1, open(r"dir\my_com_server.tlb", "rb").read())],
  29     # we only want the inproc (dll) server
  30     create_exe = False
  31     )
```